# how long does Apache keep access log?

Tags: apache-2.2

how long does Apache keep access log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you delete it or rotate it from `/var/log/apache`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly OT but simply control it yourself with [Logrotate](http://www.linuxconfig.org/logrotate). The learning curve is minimum.

Some Linux distributions install it by default these days so just look in `/etc` to see if it exists on the system already.